# Jquery combine toggle with a close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to achieve something but surprisingly wasn't able to find any code online. The jquery toggle function is great but I also wanted to combine it with a "close" button inside the expanded div. That way you can toggle it open with a button outside but also have a "close" button inside to shut it. Below shows what I tried without success:

Here is the toggle code I'm starting with:
http://jsfiddle.net/uhEgG/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#country_slide").hide();
$("#country").show();

$('#country').click(function(){
$("#country_slide").slideToggle();
});
});
```

I guess I need a button inside that does something like this:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
  $('#country_slide').hide('slow', function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, you have the JS code down, so the only thing left is the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/uhEgG/2/ - the Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#country').click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").slideToggle();
    });

    $('#close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#country_slide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

and I updated the HTML:

```
<div id="country_slide">test<a href="#" id="close">Close</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one button in the "#county_slide"

```
$('#btnClose').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#country_slide').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) for **close** and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) for **open**

check [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/YwS6h/3/)

```
 $('#country').click(function () {
    $("#country_slide").slideDown();
});

$('#close').click(function () {
   $('#country_slide').slideUp();
});
```